# Postgres crashes for long query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

My postgres crashes for long query. It's on Debian 7 64bit, and postgresql-9.3.2. I uses all default configuration. Could anyone suggest what problem it could be? thanks.

---

```
 --part1:
 SELECT r1.f2 as b, r1.e as l 
 FROM r r8,r r7,r r6,r r5,r r4,r r3,r r2,r r1
 WHERE
 r1.f2=r2.f1 AND 
 r1.f2=r3.f1 AND 
 r1.f2=r4.f1 AND 
 r1.f1=r5.f2 AND 
 r1.f1=r8.f1 AND 
 r2.f1=r3.f1 AND 
 r2.f1=r4.f1 AND
 r2.f2=r6.f2 AND 
 r2.f2=r7.f1 AND 
 r3.f1=r4.f1 AND 
 r3.f2=r7.f2 AND 
 r3.f2=r8.f2 AND 
 r4.f2=r5.f1 AND 
 r4.f2=r6.f1 AND 
 r5.f1=r6.f1 AND 
 r5.f2=r8.f1 AND 
 r6.f2=r7.f1 AND 
 r7.f2=r8.f2 AND 
 r1.d=1 AND
 r2.d=1 AND
 r3.d=2 AND
 r4.d=2 AND
 r5.d=2 AND
 r6.d=2 AND
 r7.d=2 AND
 r8.d=2
 -- part2
 group by r1.f2,r1.e
 having
 calc_empty_a() AND
 calc_empty_b();
```

In the query, calc_empty_a() are just empty boolean functions (return true), so they should have no problem.

1. If I run the query in client, the server crashes. There is nothing useful information in the log (please refer to the error info at end of the post).
2. If I run the part 1 query, the query works well.
3. If I first run the part 1 query, then I run the whole query, it works well.
4. If I change the query, reduce the r numbers, for example, there are only r1 to r6 FROM tables, delete the predicates with r8, r7, but keep the part 2's GROUP BY and HAVING clause. The query still works well.
5. If the query have one empty function in HVING clause, the query also works well, but will crash if there are two functions.
6. The following query works well

   ```
    SELECT r1.f2 as b, r1.f1 as a , r1.e as e
    FROM r r8,r r7,r r6,r r5,r r4,r r3,r r2,r r1
    WHERE
    r1.f2=r2.f1 AND 
    r1.f2=r3.f1 AND 
    r1.f2=r4.f1 AND 
    r1.f1=r5.f2 AND 
    r1.f1=r8.f1 AND 
    r2.f1=r3.f1 AND 
    r2.f1=r4.f1 AND
    r2.f2=r6.f2 AND 
    r2.f2=r7.f1 AND 
    r3.f1=r4.f1 AND 
    r3.f2=r7.f2 AND 
    r3.f2=r8.f2 AND 
    r4.f2=r5.f1 AND 
    r4.f2=r6.f1 AND 
    r5.f1=r6.f1 AND 
    r5.f2=r8.f1 AND 
    r6.f2=r7.f1 AND 
    r7.f2=r8.f2  
    group by r1.f2,r1.f1, r1.e
    having
    calc_empty_a() AND
    calc_empty_a();
   ```

I have set the os to use strict overcommit mode:

```
sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=2
```

---

Error info:

at client

```
 The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

at server

```
LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2014-11-07 16:47:03 GMT
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
LOG:  redo starts at 0/2126C98
LOG:  record with zero length at 0/21A9D98
LOG:  redo done at 0/21A9D68
LOG:  last completed transaction was at log time 2014-11-07 16:47:26.844406+00
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: At the bery least we will need the query that causes the crash, PostgreSQL version number and platform and any extensions you've installed.

Comment: You need to go further back up in the logs. At a guess I'd say it's highly likely the underlying cause is an OOM kill and that you haven't followed the manual's recommendations to disable virtual memory overcommitt. You may have a very high `work_mem` setting, or be accumulating tons of `AFTER` triggers, or have found a leak... nearly impossible to say without your PostgreSQL version, your config, the first error in the log, etc.

Comment: I have updated with more details, could you please kindle help me about the problem ? @CraigRinger

Comment: You've still cut too much of the logs. Show more of the server log - from the first backend process crash or a bit before.

Comment: please see the link in main post @CraigRinger

Comment: Interesting - it isn't the OOM killer kicking in, the backends are crashing. Try to get a backtrace. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD